# JavaScript: How to rewrite code to use dynamic values instead of hard-coded ones?

Tags: javascript, webauthn, hardcode

I have following JavaScript function as code snippet:

```js
window.registerWebAuthn = function () {
            const publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions = {
                challenge: new Uint8Array(26),
                 rp: {
                    name: "Example",
                    id  : "localhost"
            },
                user: {
                    id: new Uint8Array(26),
                    name: "xyz@test.com",
                    displayName: "Foo Bar"
                }
            };
```

The string values for the following parameters are hard-coded:

- `id`
- `name`
- `displayName`

I want to rewrite this code to use dynamic values.

Can you tell me how I can do that?